# Error: An uncaught Exception was encountered

Tags: php, codeigniter

I receive this error:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function
>   Home::cadastroOrcamentoCliente(), 0 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_financas_old\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on
>   line 532 and exactly 6 expected
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_financas_old\application\controllers\Home.php
>
> Line Number: 1116
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_financas_old\index.php Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

This is my code:

```
//Inicio de desenvolvimento new window client.
    //New Página para gerar pedido de cliente.
    function cadastroOrcamentoCliente($cpfcnpj=null, $tipo_pessoa=null, $dados = null, $id_pf, $id_cliente, $id_cadastro) {
        $tipo_login = $this->session->userdata('tipo_login');
        if ($tipo_login == '1' || $tipo_login == '4' || $tipo_login == '5') {
            $dadosPessoa['tipo_pessoa'] = null;
            $dadosOrcamento['str'] = $this->load->view('admin/compras/popup_cadastro', $dadosPessoa, true);
            if ($tipo_pessoa == 1) {
                $dadosOrcamento['cpf'] = $cpfcnpj;
                $dadosOrcamento['cnpj'] = null; 
            } else if ($tipo_pessoa == 2) {
                $dadosOrcamento['cpf'] = null;
                $dadosOrcamento['cnpj'] = $cpfcnpj;
            } else {
                $dadosOrcamento['cpf'] = $cpfcnpj;
                $dadosOrcamento['cnpj'] = $cpfcnpj; 
            }

            if ($this->alteracao->editEndereco($id_cadastro) && $this->alteracao->editPessoaFisica($id_pf) &&
                $this->alteracao->editCliente($id_cliente) && $this->alteracao->editCadastroComum($id_cadastro) && $this->alteracao->editarDadosBancarios($id_cadastro)) {
            $data_cad = date("d/m/Y");
            $hora_cad = date("H:i:s");
            $this->alteracao->cadastroHistorico('Dados do cliente editados', $id_cadastro, $data_cad, $hora_cad);
            $this->alteracao->mensagemAlerta("Dados alterados com sucesso!", 1, "home/cadastros", $id_cadastro);

            $dadosOrcamento['orcamento'] = $this->compras_m->buscarOrcamentoAtual($this->session->userdata('id_orcamento'));
            $this->load->view('admin/head');
            $dadosBarra['dadosB'] = $this->financeiro->listaContas();
            $this->load->view('admin/barraSuperior', $dadosBarra);
            $dadosLogo['logo'] = $this->adm->retornaLogo();
            $this->load->view('admin/menu', $dadosLogo);
            $this->load->view('admin/vendas/cadastro_orcamento_cliente', $dadosOrcamento);
            $this->load->view('admin/footer');
        } else {
            $dados['mensagem'] = null;
            $this->paginas($dados);
        }
    }
    }
```

im calling here

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('pedido/cadastroOrcamentoVendaCliente') ?>">
```

just create a new screen and need additional to the project

Comment: Show us how you call `cadastroOrcamentoCliente()`

Comment: just create a new screen and need additional to the project

Comment: You still haven't shown the call to that function

Answer (score 2):

This:

> ```
> function cadastroOrcamentoCliente($cpfcnpj=null, $tipo_pessoa=null, $dados = null, $id_pf,
>                                   $id_cliente, $id_cadastro)
> ```

is fundamentally wrong to begin with.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default:

> Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected.

You need to change the order of your arguments here - the ones without default values need to come first, and the ones with only after that:

```
function cadastroOrcamentoCliente($id_pf, $id_cliente, $id_cadastro, $cpfcnpj=null,
                                  $tipo_pessoa=null, $dados = null)
```

And then you will still have to provide values for at least the first three of them in your actual call of that function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting fields to the `cadastroOrcamentoCliente` you shouldn't define a parameter count. `POST` fields are not treated as function parameters, which is why you're getting the error (you're declaring that the function must receive 6 parameters exactly, but it's getting none)

just declare the function as `function cadastroOrcamentoCliente()` and then handle the post'ed fields via `$this->input->post('fieldname')` (after validating everything with the form validation helper)